# Change PHP ResultSet value of a specific row

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, resultset

I am using PHP, Zend and MySql.

I need to change the value of some rows in a result set. I tried using foreach but I found out that the changes won't persist outside the `foreach` block, and I couldn't find a way to get the result set's number of rows so I can use a `for`.

This is what I tried:

```
$datas = $this->getClientes($search);

    foreach ($datas as $row) {
        if($row['dt_pagamento'] != NULL && $row['valor_pago'] == NULL)
            $row['valor_pago'] = $this->PesquisaBoletoCorreto($row['id_parcela']);
}
```

`getClientes` returns a result set.
`PesquisaBoletoCorreto` changes the result set's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($datas as $key => $row) {
    if($row['dt_pagamento'] != NULL && $row['valor_pago'] == NULL)
        $datas[$key]['valor_pago'] = $this->PesquisaBoletoCorreto($row['id_parcela']);
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. It sets the whole row to the value returned by the function. Now I am trying to access the column that I want. But your with your solution the value is changed outside the foreach, and that's something.

Comment: I dont' know why but now it worked. Didn't have to change anything. Thanks.